# How to mass de-register file association in OS X

Tags: macos, file-association, parallels

Ever since I installed Parallels Desktop on my Mac, it associated a ton of applications as links to Parallels Desktop.

I use Alfred heavily, and often accidentally I'll choose an app that's associated with Parallels so it will begin to launch the VM. I never want to do this though – if I want to do something on the VM I'll just launch the VM.

Most of the apps can simply be deleted in OS X, some need to be re-pointed to a Mac handler.

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think the easiest solution – rather than trying to disassociate file types with Windows applications – would be to disable the sharing of Windows applications altogether.

You should be able to do that by configuring your Windows VM, and then unchecking *Share Windows applications with Mac*.

[image]